# Node.js: setTimeout callbacks for same delay called synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I have the following code to demonstrate the issue:

```
let count = 5;
while (count--) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('timeout');
        process.nextTick(() => {
            console.log('tick');
        });
    }, 0);
}

const largeNumber = 20000;
for (let i = 0; i < largeNumber; i += 1) {
    for (let j = 0; j < largeNumber; j += 1) {
        // do nothing here, just be sure all the setTimeout callbacks are in the queue when exiting sync code
    }
}
```

The output I expect is the following:

```
timeout
tick
timeout
tick
timeout
tick
timeout
tick
```

Because the event loop checks the `timeouts` queue, it founds the first `setTimeout` callback, runs it, and check the `nextTick` queue after. And for the further `setTimeout` callbacks it should do the same.

But I get the following output:

```
timeout
timeout
timeout
timeout
timeout
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
```

Why?

Comment: you can take a look [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick) for a better understanding of `process.nextTick()`

Comment: Why is that behaviour a problem for you?

Comment: @Bergi , I just don't understand why it works like this. If I register a `process.nexTick()`, the callback of it should be executed before all other `timeouts`.

Comment: @bergi i actually agree with the OP that this behaviour does not mactch the nodejs docs.

Comment: @JonasW. Also the nodejs guide doesn't mention promises at all, which is negligent these days. (Unfortunately it doesn't say when it was written)

Comment: [This tool](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=CnZhciBjb3VudCA9IDU7CndoaWxlIChjb3VudC0tKSB7CiAgICBzZXRUaW1lb3V0KGZ1bmN0aW9uIHRpbWVvdXQoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coInRpbWVvdXQhIik7CiAgICAgICAgcHJvY2Vzcy5uZXh0VGljayhmdW5jdGlvbiB0aWNrKCkgewogICAgICAgICAgICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygidGljayIpOwogICAgICAgIH0pOwogICAgfSwgNTAwMCk7Cn0K!!!) allows you "debug" the callback stack in a nodejs application. Take a look of your snippet code running for a better visualization of how it is beeing executed. Just press `Save + Run` to initialize.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` and `nextTick` will each put a function on a queue of functions to call later.

When the JavaScript event loop isn't busy doing something else, it will look at that queue of functions to see if any are due to be run.

When the first timed out function is run, it uses `nextTick` to put a function on the end of the queue (due to run as soon as possible).

However, the next function on the queue is the next function put there by `setTimeout` and it is **already due**, so it runs first (and so on).

Comment: According to the document sent by @AlexandreMiziara, it should check the `nextTickQueue` before getting the next callback from `timers` queue 
"This is because process.nextTick() is not technically part of the event loop. Instead, the nextTickQueue will be processed after the current operation completes, regardless of the current phase of the event loop."

Comment: Its clear that the next `setTimeout` is already due, but the `nextTick` should be executed before all timeout callbacks.

Comment: @Adam "*when the event loop enters a given phase, it will execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed.*" suggests that multiple callbacks from the timeout queue can be called in the same phase

Comment: @bergi but the `process.nextTick` callback should be called *after the call stack unwinded*, therefore before the next timeout callback is executed.

Comment: respectfully downvoted since the answer is incorrect.  As others have pointed out, the `nextTickQueue` would normally be processed after each `setTimeout` callback...but in this case it is not due to the [deduplication optimization](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#deduplication).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [**Deduplication**](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#deduplication):

> For the `timers` and `check` phases, there is a single transition between C to JavaScript for multiple immediates and timers. This deduplication is a form of optimization, which may produce some unexpected side effects.

Your code exhibits the "unexpected side effects" caused by the deduplication optimization.

In fact, the example in the doc is very similar to your sample code.  They are using `setImmediate` instead of `setTimeout`, but the concept is the same:

When there are multiple timer events waiting in the `check` phase, `Node` processes **all of them** before processing the `nextTickQueue`.

So because all of the `setTimeout` calls use a timeout of `0`, the callbacks all end up in the queue at the same time and due to the deduplication optimization, `Node` processes **all of them** which causes `'timeout'` to be printed all 5 times.  Once all of the `setTimeout` callbacks run, `Node` processes the `nextTickQueue` which causes all five `process.nextTick` callbacks to run which causes `'tick'` to be printed 5 times.

---

Note that if you introduce a tiny variable `delay` so the timer events don't end up in the queue during the same `check` phase you will avoid the deduplication optimization and will get the output you were expecting:

```
let count = 5;
let delay = 0;
while (count--) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
    process.nextTick(() => {
      console.log('tick');
    });
  }, delay += 1);  // use a tiny variable delay
}

const largeNumber = 20000;
for (let i = 0; i < largeNumber; i += 1) {
  for (let j = 0; j < largeNumber; j += 1) {
    // do nothing here, just be sure all the setTimeout callbacks are in the queue when exiting sync code
  }
}
```

Output:

```
timeout
tick
timeout
tick
timeout
tick
timeout
tick
```

Comment: amazing answer, this helped me with my problem. thank you